# Estimation of errors in actual experiments

Tags: estimation, error-analysis

I encountered a statement in a research paper I read which confused me-

“In order to estimate the random error in our data, we calculated the average distance between a line of best fit and the collected points. For points R < 4 kpc, we assume a linear curve, and for points R > 4 kpc we assume a flat rotation curve. “

No matter what model of making a best fit curve they use, it doesn’t mean anything physical. The errors bars are just essentially a mathematical quantity. I can slightly tweak the best fit to make error bars smaller or larger as per my wish. So my question is-

1. Is this method of error estimation actually common or the researchers where just lazy here?
2. If this is actually a valid method, what is its physical significance? Like what would these error bars even help me in deciding if I can control them based on my model of fitting.

Research paper( the mentioned statement is on page 4 )-

[https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwipm96MvLeCAxVcbWwGHdxHDiEQFnoECAgQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.spsnational.org%2Ffile%2F910941%2Fdownload%3Ftoken%3DPlACrorh%23%3A~%3Atext%3DAlthough%2520its%2520nature%2520is%2520not%2Cour%2520galaxy%252C%2520Sagittarius%2520A*.&usg=AOvVaw1fMjunnM80KjhgN3Wv0URp&opi=89978449](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwipm96MvLeCAxVcbWwGHdxHDiEQFnoECAgQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.spsnational.org%2Ffile%2F910941%2Fdownload%3Ftoken%3DPlACrorh%23%3A%7E%3Atext%3DAlthough%2520its%2520nature%2520is%2520not%2Cour%2520galaxy%252C%2520Sagittarius%2520A*.&usg=AOvVaw1fMjunnM80KjhgN3Wv0URp&opi=89978449)